# Using sed to scrub a file for environment configs

Tags: bash, sed, zsh

Currently, my `.zshrc` file maintains not only a laundry list of aliases i like to keep track, but also a few secrets/tokens that get sourced whenever i start up a new terminal, e.g

```
# Artifactory Config
export CREDENTIALS_USR=***
export CREDENTIALS_PSW=***
```

I am working on setting up a remote repository where I can store my `.zshrc`, mainly so that I can keep my aliases checked into source control, so if my laptop were to break, that's one less thing I'd have to start over with when i get a new computer.

I originally had an alias, `cpzsh`, which did the following:

```
alias cpzsh='cp ~/.zshrc .'
```

and when i execute it from the root of my git repo, copies my zshconfig to the current directory (in this case my local git repo). After this I need to manually go in and scrub my secrets prior to pushing to my remote repo.

This is really easy to screw up if I were to forget, so I tried putting together a better `cpzsh` command using `sed` that could edit my file inline, and then pipe the scrubbed `.zshrc` to my local repo:

```
alias cpzsh='sed "/CREDENTIALS_/d" ~/.zshrc > .zshrc'
```

However, this led to some adverse effects, because **the above line** also got scrubbed from my `.zshrc`!  This is because it's traversing the file for the substring `CREDENTIALS_` in a line, which it deletes.  So it not only deletes my artifactory credentials (which it should do), but it also deletes the line that contains the substring to delete (which it should not do!)

I am aware that `sed` also allows you to hard-code the lines to delete, but I'd rather not run the risk of assigning my secrets in certain lines, only for those lines to suddenly change for whatever reason and i unsuspectingly push my secrets to github.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: What about `alias cpzsh='sed "/^export CREDENTIALS_/d" ~/.zshrc > .zshrc'`  That way the line has to have export CREDENTIALS_ at the beginning and the cpzsh alias doesn't match.

Comment: FWIW what I do instead is check into source control a template of my bashrc, and a script to generate the real bashrc from the template + machine-local config file (which could contain your secrets) and isn't checked into source control.

Comment: Wouldn't 'sed "/^export CREDENTIALS_/d" ~/.zshrc > .zshrc' just truncate the file before `sed` can read it?

Answer (score 0):

How about you scrub the *values* but leave the `export CREDENTIALS_...` lines in the file?

```sh
alias cpzsh="sed 's/\(CREDENTIALS_[^=]*=\).*/\1REDACTED/;' ~/.zschrc ."
```